# How to fail sub box if any command job fail in it | Autosys |

Tags: autosys

I have a scenario where i want my Sub box to fail if any command job fails which is inside it

**For example :** Below is my Autosys Structure

```
DEMO_PARENT_BOX_ABC_T
     DEMO_SUB_BOX_ABC_T
        DEMO_SUB_COMMAND_JOB_T1
        DEMO_SUB_COMMAND_JOB_T2
```

If my command job : `DEMO_SUB_COMMAND_JOB_T1` which is inside **Sub Box** fail `[FA]` then my `DEMO_SUB_BOX_ABC_T` should Fail `FA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default is when all of the jobs that are contained in that box job completes, box is marked as success.
However, you can control the completion state of box jobs by specifying the optional `box_success` and `box_failure` attributes when you define box jobs.

For your case,

```
insert_job: DEMO_SUB_BOX_ABC_T
job_type: box
box_failure: failure(DEMO_SUB_COMMAND_JOB_T1)
```

Refer more on Page 193
[WA_AE_User_ENU.pdf](https://ftpdocs.broadcom.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Workload%20Automation%20AE%20Release%2011%203%206%20-%20Public%20Access-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/PDF/WA_AE_User_ENU.pdf)

Comment: How can we do that if the job goes to inactive state?